# Node.js optimist module - assign all arguments following flag to flag

Tags: node.js

I am using optimist for node.js, and want to parse the input like this:

```
$ command some args -m this is the message
```

into this

```
{argv:{_:['some','args'],m:'this is the message'}}
```

is this possible with optimist?
is this possible in general?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing this, which works for my use case:

```
#!/usr/bin/env coffee

args = process.argv

o = {_:[],$0:[]}
flags = {s:'state',m:'message',e:'editor',t:'type'}
i = -2
na = false # next argument: false/opt/flag

for arg in args
  if m = arg.match /^--(.+?)(=(.+))?$/
    na = m[1]
    o[m[1]] = m[3] || true
  else if m = arg.match /^-(.+)/
    na = flags[m[1]]
    o[na] = true
    if !na
      console.log 'Unknown flag: '+m[1]
      process.exit 1
  else if ++i > 0 # ignore first two args which are node and app
    if na == 'message'
      o.message = [arg]
    else if na != false
      o[na] = arg
    else
      if o.message
        o.message.push arg
      else
        o._.push arg
    na = false
  else
    o['$0'].push arg

if o.message
  o.message = o.message.join ' '

console.log o
```

### EDIT:

Actually there are still problems with this method. I ended up doing something else, but am still in search of a better solution. I think I am going to end up writing a small peg parser to parse the command line options how I want.

Answer (score 2):

In general it's the responsibility of the shell to group space-containing arguments, not the argument parser. This is generally done by the user quoting multi-word arguments (single or double quotes in Unix-type shells, only double quotes are recognized in Windows).

In Optimist you *could* do something like:

```
var argv=require('optimist').argv;
if (argv.m) {
  argv.m=argv.m+' '+argv._.join(' ');
}
```

which would work as you expect *if* `-m` is the last argument. However, if you did something like `command ... -m hello there -q now here`, `argv.m` would wind up being "hello there here" which is probably not what you'd want.

Comment: I think your solution would produce for my example, `'some args this is the message'` for `m`, but I only want args after the `m` to be part of the message... besides rewriting the optimist parser any ideas?

Comment: People who are comfortable with command lines are also comfortable with using quotes to group arguments. What you want is quite nonstandard, and would actually confuse most such people. If your target audience is in fact people who *aren't* comfortable around command lines, you should seriously choose a different kind of interface.

Comment: that does not really help to answer my question.